# winforms messagebox background colour

Tags: winforms

I am new to winforms and I want to keep things simple

When I create a message box: I notice the top half is white background while the lower half is grey (!!!)

(what I really want is all background white).

But even the VisualStudio dialog doesn't behave this way

Can someone please help me?

Do I need to write some custom code ?

I would post the image but not allowed;(
Thanks

Comment: it depends of the platform if im correct.

Comment: platform? It happens on windows7. I didn't try on any other platform.

Comment: Yes it's a windows7 thing:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/winforms/thread/43214811-9345-43ef-b96a-9944bce92068   does that mean it would be acceptable to users ?

Comment: make a custom form instead that looks similar but differs in colour.

Answer (score 0):

MessageBoxes are displayed by the operating system.  If the options that are available aren't good enough, then you have to make your own form.